# PySpark - WithColumn

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I am new to Pyspark and databricks, I am aware of some basic knowledge of it and now I am having a hard time understanding one expression.

```py
#Calculating workdays using workdaycal()
dfx = (df.withColumn('DAYS_OUTSTANDING_WORKDAYS_1',(workdaycal(holidays_list)(col("OPEN_DATE_TIME_GMT"),col("CURRENT_DATE_TIME_GMT"))).cast(DoubleType()))
      .withColumn('TAT_RESOLVED_WORKDAYS_1',(workdaycal(holidays_list)(col("OPEN_DATE_TIME_GMT"),col("LAST_RESOLVED_DATE_TIME_GMT_1"))).cast(DoubleType()))
      .withColumn('TAT_CLOSED_WORKDAYS_1',(workdaycal(holidays_list)(col("OPEN_DATE_TIME_GMT"),col("CLOSED_DATE_TIME_GMT_1"))).cast(DoubleType()))
)
```

In the above code, I am unable to figure out what does `(workdaycal(holidays_list)(col("OPEN_DATE_TIME_GMT"),col("CURRENT_DATE_TIME_GMT")))` do.

`workdaycal` is a user defined function which is like this

```py
def get_bizday(sdate,edate,holidays_list):
  h1,m1,s1=sdate.hour,sdate.minute,sdate.second  
  // further code in the function and return a float value at the end.
  return float(val)

def workdaycal(holidays):
  return udf(lambda l,e: get_bizday(l, e, holidays))
```

`holiday_list` is list of dates which I am passing to `workdaycal`.

Could anyone help me in figuring out what does this expression do?

Comment: `workdaycal` defines an inline user defined function which accepts two columns and forwards these two args and the list of dates as third arg to function `get_bizday()`. The two columns passed are `OPEN_DATE_TIME_GMT` and `CURRENT_DATE_TIME_GMT` for the first call. Like for any UDF, the function runs for each row of the dataframe.

Comment: If those are the args passed to get_bizday, why is it not written like this -> 
workdaycal(holidays,col(OPEN_DATE_TIME_GMT ),col(CURRENT_DATE_TIME_GMT)). 

Is there any documentation that i can refer to understand these conscepts?

Comment: You can declare `get_bizday` as [udf](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.udf.html#pyspark.sql.functions.udf), (optionally) [broadcast](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.Broadcast.html) list `holiday_list` and then call `get_bizday(col(OPEN_DATE_TIME_GMT),col(CURRENT_DATE_TIME_GMT))` and inside `get_bizday` use broad casted `holiday_list`.

Comment: `workdaycal` returns a UDF, that's the second set of args are passed to it, ultimately calling the UDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have simplified your use case for reproducing the results. In the simplified form, the UDF returns string representation of the input arguments.

At present, your problem statement is as follows:

- `workdaycal` returns a "udf".
- `workdaycal(holidays_list) (col(...),col(...))` first calls `workdaycal()` which returns "udf" and this "udf" is called and the two "col(...)" are passed along with global variable `holidays_list``.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

df = spark.createDataFrame([["2022-01-01 09:00:00", "2022-01-01 08:00:00"],["2022-01-02 10:00:00", "2022-01-02 07:30:00"]], ["OPEN_DATE_TIME_GMT", "CURRENT_DATE_TIME_GMT"])

def get_bizday(sdate, edate, holidays_list):
  return str(f"sdate={sdate}, edate={edate}, holidays_list={holidays_list}")

def workdaycal(holidays):
  return udf(lambda l,e: get_bizday(l, e, holidays))

holidays_list = ["Saturday", "Sunday"]

df = df.withColumn("DAYS_OUTSTANDING_WORKDAYS_1", (workdaycal(holidays_list)(col("OPEN_DATE_TIME_GMT"),col("CURRENT_DATE_TIME_GMT"))).cast(StringType()))
```

You can simplify this as a direct call to function `get_bizday`; but there is a problem: `holidays_list` is not a Spark type (it is python list).

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([["2022-01-01 09:00:00", "2022-01-01 08:00:00"],["2022-01-02 10:00:00", "2022-01-02 07:30:00"]], ["OPEN_DATE_TIME_GMT", "CURRENT_DATE_TIME_GMT"])

@udf(returnType=StringType())
def get_bizday(sdate, edate, holidays_list):
  return str(f"sdate={sdate}, edate={edate}, holidays_list={holidays_list}")

holidays_list = ["Saturday", "Sunday"]

df = df.withColumn("DAYS_OUTSTANDING_WORKDAYS_1", get_bizday(col("OPEN_DATE_TIME_GMT"), col("CURRENT_DATE_TIME_GMT"), holidays_list))
```

This results in error complaining that `holidays_list` should be one of the specified Spark types:

> TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: ['Saturday', 'Sunday'] of type <class 'list'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.

You can solve this by removing `holidays_list` from parameter list, and [broadcasting](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.Broadcast.html) it and accessing it in "udf" with `holidays_list_broadcast.value`. A broadcasted read-only shared global variable is cached and available on all nodes in the cluster.

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([["2022-01-01 09:00:00", "2022-01-01 08:00:00"],["2022-01-02 10:00:00", "2022-01-02 07:30:00"]], ["OPEN_DATE_TIME_GMT", "CURRENT_DATE_TIME_GMT"])

holidays_list_broadcast = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(holidays_list)

@udf(returnType=StringType())
def get_bizday(sdate, edate):
  return str(f"sdate={sdate}, edate={edate}, holidays_list={holidays_list_broadcast.value}")

df = df.withColumn("DAYS_OUTSTANDING_WORKDAYS_1", get_bizday(col("OPEN_DATE_TIME_GMT"),col("CURRENT_DATE_TIME_GMT")))
```

Now you are calling `get_bizday()` in a simpler and readable way.